# R function to count proportion of box types per site

Tags: r, group-by, mutate

I'm looking for some help to produce a new column of my dataset that will act as an "adjustment" number to overcome the limitation of having unequal numbers of each box type on each site.
I have four sites A,B,C and D and 8 treatments/types of boxes on the sites. This was set up before I came onto the project so there are not equal numbers of each type of boxes on each site. The boxes have been checked on multiple dates, and although all boxes on a single site will be checked on the same date, the boxes on other sites will be checked on different dates.

What I'm trying to produce is a count of number of that box type on that site/total number of boxes on that site.

My data is structured similar to the following:

```
# A tibble: 16 × 5
   Site  ID    Date       Type  Count
   <fct> <fct> <date>     <fct> <dbl>
 1 A     101   2024-02-02 x         4
 2 A     101   2024-02-02 y         6
 3 A     101   2024-02-02 x         9
 4 B     103   2024-02-01 x        10
 5 B     103   2024-02-01 z         2
 6 C     106   2024-01-30 y         8
 7 D     108   2024-01-26 x         5
 8 D     108   2024-01-26 z         6
 9 A     101   2024-01-24 x         3
10 A     101   2024-01-24 y         3
11 A     101   2024-01-24 x         4
12 B     103   2024-01-21 x         8
13 B     103   2024-01-21 z         5
14 C     106   2024-01-20 y         5
15 D     108   2024-01-19 x         7
16 D     108   2024-01-19 z         7

structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("101", 
"103", "106", "108"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(19755, 
19755, 19755, 19754, 19754, 19752, 19748, 19748, 19746, 19746, 
19746, 19743, 19743, 19742, 19741, 19741), class = "Date"), Type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("x", 
"y", "z"), class = "factor"), Count = c(4, 6, 9, 10, 2, 8, 5, 
6, 3, 3, 4, 8, 5, 5, 7, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

There are a lot more entries than this but you get the gist. The site column relates to the group, the ID column is a location on the site. My example here is not very good at showing this because there aren't enough lines but each unique ID has 3 boxes associated with that location (though they may be the same or different types). Date is a check date. Type of box is what I want to examine and count is the result count within that individual box on that date.

This is what I wrote initially but it isn't producing the output I hoped for.

```
mutated table <- df %>%
  group_by(Site, Type, ID) %>%
  mutate(n_unique = n_distinct(ID)*3) %>%
  mutate(n_boxes = n_distinct(Site)*3) %>%
  mutate(Adjustment = n_boxes / n_unique)
```

Thank you in advance for any corrections or alternative solutions you can help me with.

EDIT - additional info

I'm looking for an output that is a new column (I called n_unique above) that has the number of all types of boxes in that site, without duplicating. It would need to count number of unique combinations of ID and site and times that by 3. I based this on the ID column because each unique ID on each site has 3 boxes. I would anticipate the n_unique to be the same number for every row with the same site, so 4 numbers repeated down the table.

Then I would like to make another column I called "n_boxes" in my attempt that would have the number of each type of boxes in that site. So for example if the first observation is Site a, Type x, "n_boxes" would be a count of the number of observations that are both site a and type x.

From this I would like to create another column called "adj_modifier" which would be a measure of n_boxes/n_site which I could multiply my counts by to get a count that would be adjusted for the proportion of those box types on that particular site.

I am sure that there is something wrong with my grouping and the columns I'm referencing but can't quite understand how to get the desired result.

Comment: What would you want the output of these sample data to look like? Could you edit your question to include this desired output? Also, "isn't working" doesnt really provide us with any tangible way forward - **why** isn't it working? Throwing an error? Not desired output? Just trying to get you the help you need - good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith hello thank you for reading my question. I have added some additional information on the post about what the desired output is and where I think I'm going awry

Comment: I don't understand. The notion (to me) of *"number of all types of boxes"* in this case would never exceed 3; further, using `* 3` on one of your counts assumes that all site/id pairs have all types, which I don't know enough to say is safe. Further, while the additional explanation in your question is good, you never explain why the code you have here is not correct. For absolutely clarity, please provide the actual numbers for your sample data here, perhaps added as a column in this sample frame (even if you have to type them in manually for these 16 rows). Thanks!

Comment: I second this. Providing your desired output for your sample dataset gives us a clearer explanation and even helps us to better understand your attempted code, why it failed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Site, ID, Type) %>%
  mutate(sumCount_siteidtype = sum(Count)) %>%
  group_by(Site, ID) %>%
  mutate(sumCount_siteid = sum(Count)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 × 7
#    Site  ID    Date       Type  Count sumCount_siteidtype sumCount_siteid
#    <fct> <fct> <date>     <fct> <dbl>               <dbl>           <dbl>
#  1 A     101   2024-02-02 x         4                  20              29
#  2 A     101   2024-02-02 y         6                   9              29
#  3 A     101   2024-02-02 x         9                  20              29
#  4 B     103   2024-02-01 x        10                  18              25
#  5 B     103   2024-02-01 z         2                   7              25
#  6 C     106   2024-01-30 y         8                  13              13
#  7 D     108   2024-01-26 x         5                  12              25
#  8 D     108   2024-01-26 z         6                  13              25
#  9 A     101   2024-01-24 x         3                  20              29
# 10 A     101   2024-01-24 y         3                   9              29
# 11 A     101   2024-01-24 x         4                  20              29
# 12 B     103   2024-01-21 x         8                  18              25
# 13 B     103   2024-01-21 z         5                   7              25
# 14 C     106   2024-01-20 y         5                  13              13
# 15 D     108   2024-01-19 x         7                  12              25
# 16 D     108   2024-01-19 z         7                  13              25
```

If you're using `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer (`packageVersion("dplyr")`), you can make that a little shorter with:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(sumCount_siteidtype = sum(Count), .by = c(Site, ID, Type)) %>%
  mutate(sumCount_siteid = sum(Count), .by = c(Site, ID))
```

Comment: Hello again @r2evans, thanks for reading my question. That isn't quite what I'm after sorry. I'll edit my original post to provide some more detail as I can't fit it in the comments.

Comment: I know OP is apparently needs something else, but here's another way to get what you provided above :) ```grp_ls <- list(SiteID = c("Site", "ID"), SiteIDType = c("Site", "ID", "Type"));map(names(grp_ls), ~df %>% summarise(!!.x := sum(Count), .by = grp_ls[[.x]])) %>% reduce(full_join, .init = df)```